# Airflow 2.0.1 : Write logs in Local Timezone

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

By default, airflow 2.0.1 write logs in `UTC` timezone. But I want the logs to write in Local/Machine [non UTC] timezone. I tried changing below. But no luck

`AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE: Asia/Kolkata`

`AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: Asia/Kolkata`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the timezone in the cointainers. To do so you could pass the environment variable `TZ`. Try this:

If you have an `.env` file at the same level of the docker-compose.yaml, add this line to it:

```sh
TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

or

Simply add it to environment in `x-airflow-common` definition in the Airflow docker-compose file:

```sh
---
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  build: .
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-custom_img_name}
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    TZ: Asia/Kolkata
...
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. By the way, where do you find this `TZ` environment variable ?

Comment: Glad to hear that worked, thanks for the feedback! Please do remember to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Regarding `TZ`, is part of the variables that most Linux distributions include by default, check this [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) with more details and examples.